# Typescript and converting Object to String

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, typescript

I'm converting a Object in Typescript to a string to store into a database.

```
formData.survey_data = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(formData.survey_data));
```

The output works,in the browser but typescript insists I have an error.

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

What does that even mean?

Comment: What is the type of `survey_data`?

Comment: I defined it as an array, that was my issue.  I defined it as an array and tried to make it a string.

Answer (score 4):

```
formData.survey_data = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(formData.survey_data));
```

Based on the code provided, I would assume that `survey_data` is type `any[]`.  You are serializing your object and trying to assign it to that property.  TypeScript is strongly typed and won't allow you to do that even though JavaScript may be able to handle that scenario. (Because JavaScript isn't strongly typed you can assign any object to any property).

Comment: So do you mean because I assigned it to something else before hand, it throws an error because I try to reassign it?

Comment: Somewhere in the code formData.survey_data has a has a class/property definition which is specifies that it is of type any[]. If you want to change it you have to find that.

Comment: Figured it out!  I defined formData.survey_data as an array earlier and not a string.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: glad i could help!